# How csv should look if there is an object list within exportable object?

Tags: java, csv

Just interested how should csv look for object csv export that contains other object list.

For example, i have an object Customer that has columns:

- Id
- Name
- Email
- Products bought

Products bought is an object list of products that this user have purchased.

Does anyone know how should look csv for this kind of export?

Comment: CSV is not a good format for this kind of data. Consider JSON, XML, YAML, ... Anything that supports *structure*.

Comment: Csv isn't even very good for storing multi-line values, like paragraphs, without a lot of headache. If you have structured data, there are better serialization formats you can use for storing and importing.

Comment: @LutzHorn, i am working with what i got. The only option for me is csv.

Comment: That's a stupid option and it will give you a bad headache. It is almost impossible to export structured, multidimensional data into a tabular format.

Comment: You could put in one product per customer and repeat customer on multiple lines?
Otherwise you're going to need a custom delimiter for the products and it's properties.
If you can put out two csv's one for products by id and one for customers it would be a bit easier where the products bought would be a collection of ids.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty out of the scope of csv, even with xlsx at least it'd be way easier to do this, and still would not recommend that.

Comment: @Alowaniak, thanks, will approach it this way.

Comment: @RobertsKalderauskis ideally you just [don't use csv though](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're stuck with CSV, then you should output the values similar to how a SQL query would return data from a JOIN between a Customer table and a Product table, i.e. repeat the customer values for each product row.

In case of a Customer without any products, it should be like a LEFT JOIN, i.e. show the customer values on a line by itself.

Example:

```
CustId, Name, Email, ProdId, Product, Price, Count
1, John Doe, jdoe@example.com, 300, Milk, 3.49, 2
1, John Doe, jdoe@example.com, 418, Bread, 4.95, 1
3, Steve Smith, ssmith@example.com
7, Bob Bakers, bbakers@example.com, 300, Milk, 3.49, 1
7, Bob Bakers, bbakers@example.com, 347, Beer, 7.97, 1
7, Bob Bakers, bbakers@example.com, 522, Chips, 2.38, 1
```